# Find all group homomorphisms $f: \Bbb Z_6 \to S_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

> Find all group homomorphisms $f: \Bbb Z_6 \to S_3$.

I was asked this on a quiz and at the time I did not remember that the only normal subgroups of $S_3$ are $\{e\}, A_3$ and $S_3$ itself. This becomes quite straightforward from here as $\Bbb Z_6/\{e\} \cong f(\Bbb Z_6) = S_3$ but $\Bbb Z_6$ is abelian and $S_3$ is not so $\ker(f) =\{e\}$ cannot work.

The last two options work so one can conclude that there are two possible homomorpihsms.

I wanted to know if this can be done by noting that $(1)=f(0)=f(1+1+1+1+1+1)=6f(1)$ which implies that $f(1)$ needs to be an permutation $\tau \in S_3$ such that $6\tau = (1)$ i.e. multiplied six times by itself gives the identity. Is it possible to conclude this *without* computing $6\tau$ for every $\tau \in S_3$?

Comment: Such homomorphism only depend on $f(1)$ that has to have order 3...

Comment: [Here is a better duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769959/104041) by letting $n=6$ and $m=3$, since $D_3\cong S_3$.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261587/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-group-homomorphisms-from-s-3-to-mathbbz-6-math and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494614/how-many-group-homomorphism-are-there-from-a-3-to-s-3 but this is false.

Comment: I mean: it is not a duplicate of either. I agree with Shaun that it is a particular case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769959/describing-homomorphisms-from-bbb-z-n-to-d-m, but the question over there was too general to answer precisely the question here.

Comment: It used to be that the other ones were duplicates, @AnneBauval, but the OP changed it.

Comment: @Shaun, it seems to me only the second one was a duplicate. Anyway, now none is, so I think the question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for morphisms $f:\mathbb Z_n\to S_3$ for $n=3$ or $n=6$? Whatsoever, $f$ is determined by $f(1)$, which can be any element $\tau$ of $S_3$ such that $\tau^n=id$ (and knowing the normal subgroups of $S_3$ is useless).

If $n=6$, any element of $S_3$ will do (by Lagrange theorem).

If $n=3$, $f(1)$ is either $id$ or one of the two $3$-cycles. There are indeed two possibilities for $\ker(f)$, but three possibilities for $f$.

Comment: I'm looking for $n = 6$. How does Lagrange imply that any element will do?

Comment: A corollary of Lagrange's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) is that in a group of order $m$, any element $g$ satisfies $g^m=1$ (in multiplicative notation).

Comment: So $6\tau = (1)$ for every $\tau \in S_3$?

Comment: Yes, since $S_3$ is of order $6$. But this is usually written $\tau^6=id$.

Comment: That's slightly confusing as $\Bbb Z_6$ has additive order and $S_3$ multiplicative?

Comment: Both groups have order 6 (i.e. have 6 elements). This has nothing to do with the *notation for their law*, which  is $+$ for the former and $\cdot$ (or $\circ$, or blank) for the latter. So, we write $id=f(0)=f(1+1+1+1+1+1)=f(1)f(1)f(1)f(1)f(1)f(1)=f(1)^6$.